# How do you left pad a hexadecimal number?

Tags: excel, hex

If i have a set of data such as the following, how do I set it so that all numbers are 8 nibbles long?

```
A1: FF4C6EFF
A2: 286EFF
A3: 1156EFF
A4: 2806EF7
```

The `TEXT` command doesn't work.

```
=TEXT(A2, "00000000")
B2: 286EFF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `DEC2HEX` with the *places* command to do this:

```
DEC2HEX(number, [places])

=DEC2HEX(HEX2DEC(A2), 8)

B2: 00286EFF
```